# How to split bytes from calldata and convert into memory variables?

Tags: contract-development, bytes, calldata

Assume calldata for my smart contract being address as bytes, and few amounts as bytes chained together.

How can I extract the bytes for *address* and store it in

`address memory address_ =`

and the *amounts* dynamically in

`uint256 memory amount_1 =`

`uint256 memory amount_2 =`

`uint256 memory amount_3 =`

I'd ideally want to convert straight to `uint memory` and `address memory` instead of just splitting them as bytes and working with bytes in the contract logic.

- How do I split that at all to get the correct array lengths?
- How can I make my contract know at what index to split the bytes?
  Let's say there's only 2 amounts... I could pass the index for splitting it, but is that good practice? Maybe a separator byte?

I've found 2 methods on *ethereum.stackexchange*, but I don't think they would be complete without a method to split dynamically...

(1)

```
    bytes4 selector;
    assembly {
        selector := calldataload(data.offset)
    }
```

(2)

```
address(uint160(bytes20(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(...)))))
```

and I require a bit of further explanations about those methods. If you do understand them, I'll be grateful for a contribution/explanation. Thanks!